# If exist in array (php)

Tags: php, arrays

There are two arrays, that are given for `$link` from `foreach`. One time `$link` must be a first arrow, and a third - the second. So:

**1 array:**

```
Array (

[width] => 800

[height] => 1142

[hwstring_small] => height='96' width='67' [file] => 2010/04/white-1051279.jpg

[sizes] => Array (
[thumbnail] => Array ( [file] => white-1051279-100x150.jpg [width] => 100 [height] => 150 )
[medium] => Array ( [file] => white-1051279-200x285.jpg [width] => 200 [height] => 285 )
)

[image_meta] => Array ( [aperture] => 0 [credit] => [camera] => [caption] => [created_timestamp] => 0

[copyright] => [focal_length] => 0 [iso] => 0 [shutter_speed] => 0 [title] => ) )
```

**2 array:**

```
Array (

[width] => 50 [height] => 50 [hwstring_small] => height='50' width='50' [file] => 2010/04/images1.jpeg

[image_meta] => Array ( [aperture] => 0 [credit] => [camera] => [caption] => [created_timestamp] => 0

[copyright] => [focal_length] => 0 [iso] => 0 [shutter_speed] => 0 [title] => )
)
```

The difference - first one has `[sizes]`.

Searching for a way to detect, **is there `[sizes]` in given array**.

Tryed `if (in_array("[sizes]", $link)) { } else { }`, but it doesnt work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(isset($link['sizes'])) {

}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 6):

Since `sizes` is an array key you can make use of the function [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) which returns `TRUE` if the given `key` is set in the `array`.

```
if(array_key_exists('sizes',$link)) {
  // sizes exists
}else{
  // sizes does not exist.
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. Breaks all the code under if(array_key_exisits('sizes',$link)) {

Comment: @Glister: You have a typo in the function name. It should be **array_key_exists** . Here is a **working example** : http://www.ideone.com/jH9OZ

Answer (score 3):

```
if (isset($theArray['sizes'])) {...}
```